# How to insert an image inside a ggsurvplot?

Tags: r, image, ggplot2

I would like to insert an image inside/over a ggsurvplot.
How can I achieve this?

Let's draw a minimal working example of a ggsurvplot:

```
require (survminer)
require (survival)
fit2 <- survfit (Surv (entry, futime, death) ~ 1, myeloma)
ggsurvplot (fit2,
            data = myeloma,
            ggtheme = theme_gray(),
            legend = "none",
            risk.table = TRUE)
```

[image: ggsurvplot]

How can I insert an image on this ggsurvplot, for a example the R_logo to produce something like this (images assemble with Powerpoint) ?

[image: ggsurvplot with R logo]

I know how to do it with "standard" ggplot but, not with ggsurvplot.

Any clue ?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Charles

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option to add an image to your survival plot would be to use `ggplot2::annotation_custom`. The only difference compared to a default `ggplot` is that a `ggruvplot` is a list where the plot is stored as an element named `plot`. Hence, we have to add the image to this list element:

```r
require(survminer)
require(survival)
library(ggplot2)

fit2 <- survfit(Surv(entry, futime, death) ~ 1, myeloma)

gg <- ggsurvplot(fit2,
  data = myeloma,
  ggtheme = theme_gray(),
  legend = "none",
  risk.table = TRUE
)

fn <- tempfile(pattern = ".png")
download.file("https://www.r-project.org/logo/Rlogo.png", fn)
image <- png::readPNG(fn)
gg$plot <- gg$plot +
  annotation_custom(
    grob = grid::rasterGrob(
      image = image,
      x = unit(1, "npc") - unit(1, "mm"),
      y = unit(1, "npc") - unit(1, "mm"),
      vjust = 1, hjust = 1,
      width = unit(.25, "npc"),
      height = unit(.25, "npc")
    )
  )

gg
```

[image]

**EDIT** One option to add a black frame around the image would be to add a `rectGrob` on top of the image via a second `annotation_custom`.

```
gg$plot <- gg$plot +
  annotation_custom(
    grob = grid::rasterGrob(
      image = image,
      x = unit(1, "npc") - unit(1, "mm"),
      y = unit(1, "npc") - unit(1, "mm"),
      vjust = 1, hjust = 1,
      width = unit(.25, "npc"),
      height = unit(.25, "npc")
    )
  ) +
  annotation_custom(
    grob = grid::rectGrob(
      x = unit(1, "npc") - unit(1, "mm"),
      y = unit(1, "npc") - unit(1, "mm"),
      vjust = 1, hjust = 1,
      width = unit(.25, "npc"),
      height = unit(.25, "npc"),
      gp = grid::gpar(col = "black", fill = NA)
    )
  )

gg
```

[image]

Comment: Thank youn again Stefan!

Comment: If I want to put a black frame or or border to the inserted figure, how should I proceed?

Comment: One option would be to add a rectGrob on top of the image via a second annotation_custom. See my edit.